# SQL Server Profiler - How to filter trace to only display inserts, updates and deletes to one database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, profiler

How do I limit a SQL Server Profiler to trace only inserts, updates and deletes to a specific database?

Comment: [SQL Server Profiler - How to filter trace to only display events from one database?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/272780/1820861) over on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can narrow down the list by specifying DatabaseName or DatabaseID in Column Filters:

[image: DBName]
[image: DBID]

Note however that you need to check the box "show all columns" first.

As for inserts, updates and deletes you can filter by text column at the same place:

[image]

Comment: Note: You can't modify any settings or filters while your trace is running

Answer (score 3):

You can filter by database name or database id.

Use `SP_trace_setfilter` to filter for one database.

[sp_trace_setfilter (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-trace-setfilter-transact-sql)

If you are doing from GUI (which I do not recommend, you are better off with a server side trace), click filter columns and then chose DatabaseName.  See the picture below for doing it via GUI:

[image]